# This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' - Multiple WHEREs and LIMITS

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to do the `SELECT` with a `WHERE IN` that contains a `LIMIT` (below), which apparently isn't supported by MariaDB:

```
This version of MariaDB doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

I've looked at other solutions here that recommend using `INNER JOIN`, but these examples won't work, as I've got two `WHERE` queries that both contain a `LIMIT`

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE uuid IN (
  SELECT uid FROM table1
  WHERE updated_at LIKE '2019-07-12 08%'
  AND player_id IS NOT NULL
  LIMIT 1
)
OR uuid IN (
  SELECT old_uuid FROM table1
  WHERE updated_at LIKE '2019-07-12 08%'
  AND player_id IS NOT NULL
  LIMIT 1
)
```

The result should be the same as doing:

```
SELECT uuid, old_uuid FROM table1
WHERE updated_at LIKE '2019-07-12 08%'
AND player_id IS NOT NULL
LIMIT 1
```

Getting the two values then inserting them into:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE uuid LIKE *VALUE1* --(uuid from above)
OR uuid LIKE *VALUE2* --(old_uuid from above)
```

But I'd like to do it without having to run the first statement, copying and pasting the values into the second and re-running.

Comment: That's the second time you have asked this question without stating what you are trying to achieve, providing sample data and expected output

Comment: I genuinely wasn't aware that was a pre-requisit when asking a question. I have given an explanation as to what I expect the output to be like "The result should be the same as doing:". Had I thought that sample data would have helped with the question, then I would have provided it. Apologies if I've broken SO etiquette?

Comment: Perhaps you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Appreciate the link. It would probably be useful for that info to either be present, or linked to when a user clicks the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) here. Get the `uid` and `old_uuid` as per your conditions in the subquery (Derived Table); and then `JOIN` it to the main table matching either of them to `uuid`:

```
SELECT 
  t1.*
FROM 
  table1 AS t1 
JOIN 
(
  SELECT uid, old_uuid 
  FROM table1
  WHERE updated_at LIKE '2019-07-12 08%'
    AND player_id IS NOT NULL
  LIMIT 1
) AS dt ON dt.uid = t1.uuid 
           OR dt.old_uuid = t1.uuid
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Yes, in most scenarios ! However, many times, you simply need any random row matching the given conditions. It is helpful at those times. Looks like OP wants the same as well.